# Why would old hardware get more support on Linux than Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, display-driver

An application developer reviewed a problem I was having, where my old integrated graphics Intel(R) G45/43 Express Chipset wasn't rendering simple textures, and he said I should try using Linux because the hardware had more up to date drivers available if I did.

So why aren't the newer drivers available for windows?  If they're third party, why aren't third party drivers an option for windows?

I just don't really understand it.

Comment: "Why" question are generally asking questions that cannot be answered empirically. They also aren't generally asking for a solution to a specific problem, and so are off-topic for this site.

Comment: @music2myear
I actually had several questions: (1) is it true Linux has more support (2) are these hypothetical drivers third party and (3) why aren't these drivers available on windows
Given those questions are all important to my resolution and they all fall under the title question I felt it was fitting.  I am sorry you disagree.

Comment: If you have and actual problem, it would be better if you were to come out and state it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Linux drivers are often written and supported by the community, whereas Microsoft does not commonly write driver software for third party peripherals.

MS does supply generic drivers, but generally not device specific ones. In the windows ecosystem, once the manufacturer stops providing new driver updates for an older product, then that's kind of it.

Third party drivers are unusual these days in consumer-end computing. Since Windows Vista, for security reasons, Microsoft started requiring that all drivers loaded into the kernel be digitally signed by a certificate the OS recognizes and respects. They established the [Windows Hardware Quality Labs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHQL_Testing) process to help device manufacturers and OEMs certify and sign packages. This process initially cost money, and still requires large investments in licensing to perform the testing.

Modern Copyright enforcement is also a factor; it used to be possible to get at least tacit non-interference from companies if you disassembled their code and tweaked it a little. That just doesn't fly these days.

Modern video card drivers are very sophisticated, and must support a large array of technologies and standards like [DirectX/D3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX), [OpenGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL), [PhysX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhysX), [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA), and a host of smaller items. Development on this scale requires a team of dedicated highly skilled developers working in a well coordinated manner. DirectX is one major difference between Windows and Linux; linux for the most part doesn't use it, dramatically simplifying the endeavor.

Many companies don't release linux drivers for their devices, and don't really have the skilled staff necessary to build for the nebulously-defined prototypical linux installation (is the user running [Systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) or [SysV init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V), [X or Waylan or Mir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server), [Gnome or KDE or LXDE or MATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface), etc) so the community must fill the gap, and so they (often) do.

Comment: if they exist, then perhaps, but Microsoft requires that drivers be signed and passed through the Windows Hardware Quality Labs certification (WHQL), and the submitter must pay the costs for the evaluation, which can be in the 10s of thousands of dollars. Besides, there is less motivation to work on a windows driver for a developer.  most would just buy a new motherboard. There has to be a certain academic interest in doing so, or the vast majority of people won't bother, and its not just anyone who can write a fully featured driver.

Comment: Wonderful answers!  If you could append that to your full answer above I'll accept it.  I ask this to make it easier to be understood by future readers who might not browse the comments.

Comment: Sorry, I was editing the post while you were, and stomped your changes. I think this works better.